# How to show that an ellipse is axially parallel

Tags: geometry

Let be $ f_1 (1,0) $ and $ f_2= (-1,0) $ and $ a>2 $

$E_a := \{ p \in \mathbb{R}^2 | || p - f_1 || + ||p- f_2 || = a \} $

How can I show (with the priciple of the Gardener's Construction maybe ?)
that $E_a$ is axially parallel ?

Comment: I’m not sure that I see what the problem is. You’re giving the two foci, and they’re on the same horizontal line. Therefore the axes are parallel to the axes of the coordinate system. Or is that not what you were asking?

Comment: What is the definition of "axially parallel"?